# Spell check in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, spell-checking

We are making a Web application for Blackberry (ASP.NET). The customer would like to have a spell checking feature when editing text fields in forms (textareas).

Does anybody know how could this be done for a web application targeting the Blackberry platform?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spellcheck is enabled in all BlackBerry application by default, even on the blackberry browser.

The user has to click on the application button, and there is an option called "Checkspelling"

Here is a screenshot to show you.

[alt text http://livinloud.ca/documents/bbspellcheck.jpg](http://livinloud.ca/documents/bbspellcheck.jpg)

Comment: Thanks Livinloud, totally missed that :).